# Deploying docker-compose as yml in order to be able to scale using the same port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I've successfully managed to deploy a docker-compose.yml using docker-machine. The problem I have is with scaling. Trying to scale a node.js app that uses port 3000. How can I scale a docker-compose service. I know I can use `docker-compose scale web=3` in a swarm of 1 node (server) but this doesn't work because I specified port 3000, which results in a conflict.

How can I get it to work in a dynamic manner without resorting to using HAProxy or Nginx?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:wheezy
# replace this with your application's default port
EXPOSE 3000
ADD . /install
WORKDIR /install
ENV NODE_PATH /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
RUN npm install -g $(cat packages) && rm -rf npm_cache /tmp/* && npm install
# Install node modules and start
CMD ["npm", "install"]
CMD ["node", "."]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
    services:
      web:
        build: .
        ports:
          - "3000:3000"
        links:
          - mongo
        environment:
          - "affinity:image==node:wheezy"
      mongo:
        image: mongo
        volumes:
          - ./appdb:/data/db
    volumes:
      mongo-data:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are actually BINDING to the host, it wouldn't be possible without a proxy or load balancer.

See this issue on the topic via GitHub where a user was asking a similar question:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3088

Here is an example of how you can do it with a load balancer, making it easy:

https://github.com/vegasbrianc/docker-compose-demo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was hoping to be a little lazy but I'll take your advice and add a load balancer to the equation.

Comment: NP! I think (hope) you'll be happy to have in the long run. I'd recommend this load balancer as it can hot-update it's configuration when services scale: https://hub.docker.com/r/dockercloud/haproxy/. It is the same LB Docker uses on their official Docker Cloud.

Comment: Cool. It does look promising from peeking at the docker-compose.yml on the demo link above.